# How to Navigate to running screen if app is accessed in windows phone?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop location tracking. In this app first user opens the main screen. Then he selects to run the app which navigates to the second screen. Then it also works in the background as well. Now, if the user opens the app he should be forwarded directly to the second screen not to the first screen again. How? Any suggestions, pls post them.
//code

```
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  TimeSpan runTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Environment.TickCount - _startTime);
    timeLabel.Text = runTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
```

Comment: has the app been exited completely, or just suspended?

Comment: if app is exited without stopping, it runs in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (I think) is, when loading the first screen, to redirect to the second screen then to remove the page from the backstack.

In the first screen:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In the second screen:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Another way is to use a custom URI mapper to display the second screen when the first screen is called. It's a bit more complex but you avoid the now-useless navigation to the first screen. This code should be called only once and before the navigation, ideally during the application's initialization in App.xaml.cs:

```
var mapper = new UriMapper();

int random = new Random().Next(0, 3);

mapper.UriMappings.Add(new UriMapping
{
    Uri = new Uri("/FirstScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative),
    MappedUri = new Uri("/SecondScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
});

Application.Current.RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;
```

Comment: Hi Kookiz, i m sorry u didn't get my question. In the second screen, timer is running. So if the timer is running in the background, it should navigate to the second screen else it should start from first screen. pls check the code above which I reposted. Thank u bro.